# Minecraft Blockbench animation problem

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

With blockbench I have created a chainsaw which would work in conjunction with a datapack. Out of obvious reasons, I want the teeth to **actually spin** along the edge. So I made a 3 framed animation using Blockbench featuring the teeth running on the chainsaw.

However, I cannot find a way to activate/play this animation using commands. In my datapack, the chainsaw starts spinning if you right clicked. I want the animation to play when the player right clicked holding the chainsaw.

I have searched this topic on google and found a method called overriding default animations where you replace the pulling animation of a crossbow to the frames you have created. But this would not work in my case, since the item which I based off the chainsaw is actually a carrot_on_a_stick, which doesn't have any animation.

In short, how do I play this custom animation that I have created with blockbench in game using vanilla commands only?

Edit: to add on, these animations are not simply texture files but separate models